# How to secure the connection, data-flow between data harvester and jsonp client/user?

Tags: javascript, http, ssl, httpwebrequest, jsonp

What methods are there to secure the data-flow between a data harvester server and multiple specific jsonp users/clients ?

A simple example would be google webmaster tools . You get the js code for your domain, you put in your html file and data is harvested for your specific domain . Without proper security , one could generate headers, custom js (parse the domain specific supplied js code by the data harvester) to clone  your domain , and send data to google that would mess up the statistics of your content/user actions .

I was wodering if there is a client side solution, without any server side logic, curl requests for keys. Is there a way to do it only via js? Do ssl certificates help ?

Any lead would be very apreciated.